# Issue on concatenating files shellscipt

Tags: shell, ksh

Sorry, I'm from Brazil and my english is not fluent.

I wanna concatenate 20 files using a shellscript through cat command. However when I run it from a file, all content of files are showed on the screen.

When I run it directly from terminal, works perfectly.

That's my code above:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

set -x -a
. /PROD/INCLUDE/include.prod
DATE=`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'`
FINAL_NAME=$1

# check if all paremeters are passed

if [ -z $FINAL_NAME ]; then
   echo "Please pass the final name as parameter"
   exit 1
fi

# concatenate files

cat $DIRFILE/AI6LM760_AI6_CF2_SLOTP01* $DIRFILE/AI6LM761_AI6_CF2_SLOTP02* $DIRFILE/AI6LM763_AI6_CF2_SLOTP04* \
$DIRFILE/AI6LM764_AI6_CF2_SLOTP05* $DIRFILE/AI6LM765_AI6_CF2_SLOTP06* $DIRFILE/AI6LM766_AI6_CF2_SLOTP07* \
$DIRFILE/AI6LM767_AI6_CF2_SLOTP08* $DIRFILE/AI6LM768_AI6_CF2_SLOTP09* $DIRFILE/AI6LM769_AI6_CF2_SLOTP10* \
$DIRFILE/AI6LM770_AI6_CF2_SLOTP11* $DIRFILE/AI6LM771_AI6_CF2_SLOTP12* $DIRFILE/AI6LM772_AI6_CF2_SLOTP13* \
$DIRFILE/AI6LM773_AI6_CF2_SLOTP14* $DIRFILE/AI6LM774_AI6_CF2_SLOTP15* $DIRFILE/AI6LM775_AI6_CF2_SLOTP16* \
$DIRFILE/AI6LM776_AI6_CF2_SLOTP17* $DIRFILE/AI6LM777_AI6_CF2_SLOTP18* $DIRFILE/AI6LM778_AI6_CF2_SLOTP19* \
$DIRFILE/AI6LM779_AI6_CF2_SLOTP20* > CF2_FINAL_TEMP

mv $DIRFILE/CF2_FINAL_TEMP $DIRFILE/$FINAL_NAME
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when I run it from a file, all content of files are showed on the screen." ?

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcards like `cat $DIRFILE/AI6LM7[67]?_AI6_CF2_SLOTP*` ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem putting the cat block inside a function, and redirecting stdout to the final file.

Ex:
concatenate()